# masking a numpy array using an existing mask of the same shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

Say I have a numpy array mask called
`m1 = [[False, True, False], [True, False, True]]`
And **I want to find a mask m2** such that its (i,j) entry is True iff  `j >= 0 and m1[i, j+1] == True`. 
Any elegant and efficient ideas as to how to pull that off? 
Thanks

Comment: What is the expected shape of M2?

Comment: The same as M1 @vineetgundecha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way slicing and using binary operators:

```
m1 = np.array([[False, True, False], [True, False, True]])

m2 = np.full(m1.shape, False)
m2[:, :-1] = m1[:, 1:] | m2[:, :-1]
```

---

```
print(m2)

array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False]])
```

Comment: This is superb ! Thanks